# ServerCertificateValidationCallback Being Ignored

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I have the following code, which results in a WebException and I can't figure out why for the life of me. VS2012 / .Net 4.5 RTM on Windows 8 RTM.

```
    ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = null;
    ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

    var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

    var response = request.GetResponse();

    WebException was unhandled
    The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

I originally had the callback as its own method, which was never called.  Any ideas why I am unable to ignore SSL validation errors and send all my sensitive data to an unknown web server?

Comment: What happens when you try it with another SSL server (such as `https://www.google.com`)? I think your connection is failing before it even starts the SSL/TLS handshake.

Comment: You're right, I used another server (with valid SSL but retrieved via IP, where original server has a self-signed) and the callback executed and the content was retrieved.  Any idea what could cause the connection to break before the callback, when it works in both Firefox & IE10?

Comment: I couldn't tell you - you'd have to use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to see how your program is behaving compared to Firefox/IE. But a few things come to mind: are you using the wrong port number or not initiating the TLS handshake fast enough?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft wont allow it. It damages the platform, because it is the reason why we arent developing apps for it. (we have millions of happy customers)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f5821194-4c40-48e7-976c-3dec8864ac59/servicepointmanagerservercertificatevalidationcallback?forum=winappswithcsharp

You need a valid certificate or a real workaround. It is a big drawback for security reason.